# Can't load the pre-trained word2vec of korean language

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I would like to download and load the pre-trained word2vec for analyzing Korean text.

I download the pre-trained word2vec here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ZXk88koS2KbDhXdWg1Q2RydlU/view?resourcekey=0-Dq9yyzwZxAqT3J02qvnFwg
from the Github Pre-trained word vectors of 30+ languages: https://github.com/Kyubyong/wordvectors

My gensim version is 4.1.0, thus I used:
`KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('./ko.bin', binary=False)` to load the model. But there was an error that :

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte

I already tried many options including in stackoverflow and Github, but it still not work well.
Would you mind letting me the suitable solution?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the page at https://github.com/Kyubyong/wordvectors isn't clear about the formats this author has chosen, by looking at their source code at...

https://github.com/Kyubyong/wordvectors/blob/master/make_wordvectors.py#L61

...shows it using the Gensim model `.save()` method.

Such saved models should be reloaded using the `.load()` class method of the same model class. For example, if a `Word2Vec` model was saved with...

```
model.save('language.bin')
```

...then it could be reloaded with...

```
loaded_model = Word2Vec.load('language.bin')
```

Note, through, that:

- Models saved this way are often split over multiple files that should be kept together (and all start with the same root name) - but I don't see those here.
- This work appears to be ~5 years old, based on a pre-1.0 version of Gensim – so there might be issues loading the models directly into the latest Gensim. If you do run into such issues, & absolutely need to make these vectors work, you might need to temporarily use a prior version of Gensim to `.load()` the model. Then, you could save the plain vectors out with `.save_word2vec_format()` for later reloading across any version. (Or, using the latest interim version that can load the model, re-save the model as `.save()`, then repeat the process with the latest version that can read *that* model, until you reach the current Gensim.)

But, you also might want to find a more recent & better-documented set of pretrained word-vectors.

For example, Facebook makes FastText pretrained vectors available in both a 'text' format and a 'bin' format for many languages at https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/pretrained-vectors.html (trained on Wikipedia only) or https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html (trained on Wikipedia plus web crawl data).

The 'text' format should in fact be loadable with `KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(filename, binary=False)`, but will only include full-word vectors. (It will also be relatively easy to view as text, or write simply code to massage into other formats.)

The 'bin' format is Facebook's own native FastText model format, and should be loadable with either the [`load_facebook_model()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_model) or [`load_facebook_vectors()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_vectors) utility methods. Then, the loaded model (or vectors) will be able to create the FastText algorithm's substring-based guesstimate vectors even for many words that weren't in the model or training data.

Comment: I tried to install the version < 4.0 to use the old format, but that still exist the error : 'AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Vocab' on <module 'gensim.models.word2vec' from 'C:\\Users\\ductr\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\gensim\\models\\word2vec.py'>'
with my code:

`word2vec_path = './gensim-data/ko/ko.bin'
word2vec = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load(word2vec_path)`

Comment: Also, many thanks for your recommended source. I'll try to use it, and let u know later

Comment: To narrow in on exact which older versions you might need, you'd want to confirm with the creator of those models which version *they* used. (It might have been `0.13` based on what they mention in the README, but it's not certain.) You'd then want to try some version between `0.13` & the latest, to see if it loads the model - for example, `3.8.3` *might* work. But if it doesn't, you'd jump back further until you find one that does.

Comment: And if after trying a bunch of versions you can't find one that works, to help debugging a specific problem you'd want to share the *exact* version & *full error message* (including 'traceback' of involved lines-of-code/files) for where you got stuck. And, to the extent it's hard to do in these tiny comments, it might in such a case make sense to edit your question to append new well-formatted, complete info.

Comment: I doubt that it's worthwhile trying too hard to get this one particular set of old wiki-trained vectors working - one or the other of the FastText sets are probably as good, or better for whatever generic purposes you have. (And often as you do more advaned things, you'll want to train your own word models based on fresh, relevant data from your own problem domain.) But if you absolutely had to try to get these old models working, the major Gensim versions before the latest I'd try would be `3.8.3`, `3.3.0`, `3.0.1`, `2.3.0`, & `1.0.1`. (And you might just need one or two, unsure.)

Comment: I tried the version of 3.8.2 since my PC can not install the 3.8.3
Also, I tried the version 3.3.0 and 2.3.0. All these told me the same error that :

File "C:\Users\ductr\Python\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 1460, in unpickle

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Vocab' on <module 'gensim.models.word2vec' from 'C:\\Users\\ductr\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\gensim\\models\\word2vec.py'>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240406/discussion-between-trung-luu-and-gojomo).

Comment: I write answers so that they can become findable references helping others in the future, so I don't use Stack Overflow's weird "chat" function, which hides info from search. The error alone without the exact version, code, & full 'traceback' is not very useful for deducing what's going wrong. And still: as the output of a project with minimal docs, not updated for 5y, it's possible the files are simply broken. (Do you have any evidence anyone has gotten that file to work at any time?)

Comment: As you mentioned, the files are simply broken, thus I tried the fasttext pretrained vectors from facebook. And I tried follow the guides here: https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html
I download the Korea fasttext source here: https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/fasttext/vectors-crawl/cc.ko.300.bin.gz
But I still have some errors with `load_facebook_model` or `load_facebook_vector` such as:
name 'load_facebook_vectors' is not defined; or
module 'gensim.models' has no attribute '_fasttext_bin'

Comment: You may want to post a new question with the full details of these new problems with a new set of files - that might be problems with having the wrong (older) Gensim version ative in your environment, or imports. (For loading full modern Facebook FastText models, you should use the latest Gensim.)

Comment: thank u so much @gojomo